# What's the easiest way to cd to the deepest directory on an absolute path to a file?

Tags: command-line, cd-command

For example, I may have the following on my clipboard:

```
/Users/matt/widgets/file.txt
```

And I want to change directory to:

```
/Users/matt/widgets
```

---

`cd` doesn't work:

```
$ cd /Users/matt/widgets/file.txt
bash: cd: /Users/matt/widgets/file.txt: Not a directory
```

**What simple (i.e. easy to type) change can I make to make this easy?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're OK with front-loading the effort in order to make subsequent runs easier, you could create a function (name it whatever makes sense to you):

```
function cdfile { cd -- "$(dirname $1)"; }
```

Save such a definition to your `~/.bashrc` file.
Then, each time you have a file path that you wanted to `cd` to, you could

```
cdfile <paste path>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use dirname:

```
cd "$(dirname /Users/matt/widgets/file.txt)"
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd $(dirname /Users/matt/widgets/file.txt)`

Comment: beware of `mkdir "widget files"` (directories with spaces or tabs in them)

Comment: @Jeff Schaller  And also `mkdir 'widget " files'`  and lots of other combinations.